# Disable cursor text on secondary value axis in amstock chart

Tags: amcharts, amstock

I do have a stock panel with 2 stockGraph: an OHLC graph and a turnover graph for which they have their own valueaxis
In 3.14.5 the cursor text only shown on the 1st valueaxis [i.e. OHLC graph's valueaxis] but not on the 2nd valueaxis
I just try 3.18.6 and the cursor text show on both valueaxis too
How can i disable the text on the 2nd valueaxis ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable value balloons for individual value axes by setting [`balloon.enabled`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmBalloon#enabled) variable in that axis' config. I.e.:

Use this property to disable balloons for certain value axes. I.e.:

```
"valueAxes": [{
  // ...
  // value balloons are shown
}, {
  // ...
  "balloon": {
    "enabled": false
  }
  // value balloons are not shown
}]
```